# Documentation for Singleton in Salesforce has incorrect information

Tags: apex, governorlimits, documentation

I was reading through the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/wiki/apex_design_patterns#Singleton) in salesforce for using a singleton pattern and it is mentioned.

> Limiting Impact of Governor Limits - certain system objects and methods, such as Apex Describes, are subject to governor limits. The Singleton pattern allows repeated reference to these without breaching governor limits.

But I thought that limits around describe calls got removed in some earlier release. Is the documentation not updated? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link is to the Salesforce Developer Wiki which was [retired in 2018.](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/08/salesforce-developer-wiki-retirement.html) I would no longer treat that as documentation

> Years ago, the Salesforce Developer Wiki was a trove of valuable
> technical resources but these days, **there is a good part of those
> 1.6k pages that is now obsolete and duplicated by our documentation**. We concluded that it was time to act for the sake of the quality and
> relevance of our technical resources.

It also has the following statement at the top to signify why/when it was created:

> This is a wiki version of the Dreamforce 2012 presentation 'Apex
> Design Patterns'

Documentation now has the following url

`developer.salesforce.com/docs/....`

In terms of your question, the limits were removed in [Summer '14](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/190/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer14_release_notes.pdf) (pg. 274) so that wiki was created based on a presentation done before that occurred.

> Limits for all Apex describe calls have been removed for all API
> versions.
>
> Describe calls include describes for sObjects, fields, field
> sets, child relationships, picklists, and record types.
>
> You’re no
> longer limited to describing 100 objects or to executing 100 describe
> statements

Comment: yes you are correct. Its a wiki link and not documentation. Thanks for the clarification.